# Does the analytic function have a square root

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:U\to \mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ be a holomorphic function. Does it always have a sqare root function $g^2=f$ which is also analytic in the same region $U$?Note that $U$ represents the open unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$.

I think yes, but am not even able to provide an example of such an $f$. Should we make use of the riemann mapping theorem to produce such a function and its square root. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: *Hint:* There is a holomorphic branch of the logarithm in $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: @MartinR So does the logarithm have an analytic squareroot?

Comment: Logarithm and square root are closely connected: $\sqrt w = \exp(\frac 12 \log w)$

Comment: @MartinR so I rewrote your comment as an answer, check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal branch of the logarithm is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$. Therefore, for any holomorphic function $f:U\to \mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$, you can define
$$
 g: U \to \Bbb C, g(z) = \exp(\frac 12 \log(f(z)))
$$
which satisfies
$$
 g(z)^2 = \exp( \log(f(z))) = f(z)
$$
in $U$, i.e. it is a holomorphic square root of $f$.

Note that even more is true: In your case $U$ is the unit disk and that is a *simply connected* domain. It follows that any non-zero holomorphic function $f$ in $U$ has a holomorphic logarithm and therefore a holomorphic square root.